# How to compare objects in C#

Tags: c#

How do you compare objects in C#. Here is a sample of my code

```
namespace MyService
{
    public static class CurrentVCobj
    {
        public static string id { get; set; }
        public static string Month { get; set; }
        public static string Year { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ResponseVCObj
    {
        public static string id { get; set; }
        public static string Month { get; set; }
        public static string Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to assign values to the above objects (CurrentVCobj and ResponseVCObj) then compare(TRUE OR FALSE) them in the method below to see if they are equal

```
public static  void compareMethood(IEnumerable<tets> vc )
{             
    var myvar = vc;
    var mycac = rep.populateDict();

    foreach (var item in myvar)
    {
        ResponseVCObj.id = item.id;
        ResponseVCObj.Month = DateRange.Month;
        ResponseVCObj.Year = DateRange.Year;

        CurrentVCobj.id = currentV.Select(d => d.Value.id).ToString() ;
        CurrentVCobj.Month = currentV.Select(d => d.Value.Month).ToString();
        CurrentVCobj.Year = currentV.Select(d => d.Value.Year).ToString();

        //COMPARE OBJECTS HERE               
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `static` for these types? It does not make sense here

Comment: when comparing objects vs comparing values use Object.Equals(  ) vs if a == b as an example

Comment: @wade It is unclear what your criteria for equality is for these classes. Are you trying to compare on `id`, `Month`, `year`, object reference, some hash value?

Comment: Where does the variable `currentV` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (ResponseVCObj.Equals(CurrentVCobj))
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, is there any reason you are using static classes? Your sample code seems very bizarre to me. Your usage of LINQ seems unnecessary as well.

If you want to compare two different objects by something other than a simple reference check you need to override the Equals method.

A guide on that can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You may not realize that some people who ask questions here are beginners

Comment: Also I am using linq because I pulling data from my database.currentV is a datadictionary populated from my database

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to sound disparaging.  I just wanted to you to consider revising those issues before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in noting that you should override `object.Equals`, and that you should remove the static modifier from the classes and their members.

In addition, you should consider

- having the classes inherit from the same interface
- having the classes inherit from the same base class; if this is possible, then you can implement the equality comparison in that base class
- implementing IEquatable on each class or the base class; if there's no common base type then you probably want to implement it twice on each type -- `IEnumerable<CurrentVCobj>` and `IEnumerable<ResponseVCObj>`
- the fact that when you compare strings for equality, the results may vary from one computer to the other, depending on the culture settings on that computer.